# Firephp, class file and 'Undefined variable'

Tags: php, firebug, firephp

this is a very dumb question but i have no php pal i can fall back to, sad me ;-)

So i have this setup, i have just installed firephp:

```
/lib/firephp.php   // firephp standard library
/lib/data.php      // a php class file of my own
        |
        |-> Class Data {}   // this is the class
                  function something() { $firephp->log('whatever'); }
pre.php            // here i initialize firephp
show_data.php      // i show data from the database here


---
pre.php
---
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/intranet/lib/firephp.php');
ob_start();
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);

---
show_data.php
---
include('pre.php')
include('lib/data.php')
$c = new Data
$c->something()
```

And i get this: **Notice: Undefined variable: firephp in show_data.php**

TL;DR I initialize firephp in an include file, then include my class file, when i try to call it from inside the class it isn't able to read $firephp var...

Any tips, scolding or whatever you can help me is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way to do this:

In pre.php i created a function that creates $firephp object and then i just call that in show_data.php

```
---
pre.php
---
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/intranet/lib/firephp.php');
ob_start();

function mylog($var, $other = '') {
    $firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
    $firephp->log($var, $other);
}


---
show_data.php
---
include('pre.php')
include('lib/data.php')
mylog('whatever');
```

This works!